# nspr-devel for Debian Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, debian, rhel

I was wondering if this is possible. I am able to install nspr into CentOS;

```
yum install nspr-devel
```

I saw this is really only meant for for CentOS/RHEL/Fedora so note

http://pkgs.org/download/nspr-devel

Is there a way I can install this into the latest version of Debian with apt-get? If so, does any one have the step by step instructions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like libnspr4-dev is the package you want.

I found it using apt-cache search:

```
$ apt-cache search nspr
dnsproxy - proxy for DNS queries
libnspr4 - NetScape Portable Runtime Library
libnspr4-0d - NetScape Portable Runtime Library - transitional package
libnspr4-dbg - Debugging symbols for the NetScape Portable Runtime library
libnspr4-dev - Development files for the NetScape Portable Runtime library
python-nss - Python bindings for Network Security Services (NSS)
```

Looks like it's already in the Debian repositories, which means you don't need to get it from elsewhere.

You can see which version would be installed with apt-cache policy:

```
$ apt-cache policy libnspr4-dev
libnspr4-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2:4.9.2-1
  Version table:
     2:4.9.2-1 0
        500 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ testing/main amd64 Packages
```

If that's OK, you can install it with `apt-get install libnspr4-dev`.

If not, then you should check `/etc/apt/sources.list` to ensure that it lists a repository with the version you need.

Comment: Thanks Martin, it worked but under my CentOS I have /usr/include/nspr4 but under Debian, it is /usr/include/nspr so it kind of messes up C++ Include statements.

Comment: That sort of thing is always a pain. For portability, you probably want to look into tools like autoconf/automake, or CMake. These will help you write tests that look for the headers, and configure your build accordingly.

Comment: New thing for me! I guess I need to change everything over within the source. Tanks again